TensorFlow Object Detection is not working on Xiaomi /Oppo Devices
I am facing an issue while working with TensorFlow Lite for Android. I am using Object Detection, and so far, the detection has been working fine. However, I encountered a problem on two devices: the Xiaomi Redmi 10A and an Oppo device. On these devices, the detection is not working.
I am using CameraX to detect objects when they come under the CameraX camera preview.
There doesn't seem to be any exception that I can catch in Logcat.
Has anyone faced a similar issue before?
I debugged and tested my code on Samsung, Techno, and Vivo devices, and it works perfectly on all of them.
